# How to create one to one relationships by using one common table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I have three tables:

```
Connection(OwnerGuid, ConnectionTypeId, Connection)
Instrument(Id, Guid, Model, Name, Description)
LaboratoryInfoSystem(Id, Guid, Model, Name, Description)
```

and the `rule` is that one `Instrument` has only one connection and one `LaboratoryInfoSystem` has only one connection also. So the relationship between `Instrument` and `Connection` is one to one as well as `LaboratoryInfoSystem` and `Connection`.

The idea is that `Connection` table will hold connections for `LaboratortInfoSystem` and `Instrument`. To do that I declare one to one connection between `LaboratortInfoSystem` and `Connection` by using `Guid` field as foreign key and primary key in `Connection` table.

> Is there any better method to do that ?

Also after I use `Entity Framework` in the `Instrument` class I have this:

```
public virtual Connection Connection { get; set; }
```

but in the `Connection` i have:

```
public virtual ICollection<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }
```

which tells me that the relation is not `one-to-one`.

> How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the facts `Each Instrument has one connection` and `Each LaboratoryInfoSytem has one Connection` are NOT enough to imply `Instrument:Connection 1:1` and `LaboratoryInfoSytem:Connection 1:1`. What is missing is: Are you sure that each Connection will only belong to at most one Instrument or LaboratoryInfoSytem?

Regardless of the above point, since both Instrument and LaboratoryInfoSystem share Connection, it is not smart to just put Connection columns into both. You could make a new table which will contain the associations between Connection and (Instrument OR LaboratoryInfoSytem). The OR I'm mentioning is not code, but rather a design consideration which is called `polymorphic association` and is a kinda common design headache. I'd recommend [this article](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database) for a variety of solutions, to see what fits you best.

Edit-addition: Since from the comments you provided 1:1 relationships are true, it means that your c# code probably can't handle the logic of polymorphic associations. Maybe it would work/assert it if you were to create a unified table of Instrument/LaboratoryInfoSystem. Of course, if this is done, then you don't need a Connection_per_element or even a Connection table: you just put it all in one. However, Instrument and LaboratoryInfoSystem don't sound very similar, so I guess you'll have to go the polymorphic association route and just...be sad that your c# code can't understand it.

Comment: Yes, one `connection` will only belong to at most one `Instrument` or `LaboratoryInfoSystem` because it's unique.